# bundle vs single quantity discount

Tags: discount, quantity, bundle

I write you because I am trying to create a **shopping cart rule** that applies a **discount** to a **bundle of materials** (2 different materials in each BOM) if the user places more than 10 bundles in the basket.

What I did is creating a discount that only applies if quantity of material 1 and the quantity of material 2 are both above 10 (material 1 and material 2 form the bundle).

So far everything was working but now I have an additional material that I would like to include in the action discount. This material (material 3) is not part of any bundle but I would like to have an action that says: "if the total quantity in the basket is above 10 (e.g. 5 bundles and 5 material 3), then apply discount".

The only solution that I found so far was to state all the different combinations of quantity but I found out that Magento has a limited amount of rows of formulas :)

> Material 1 > 1; Material 2> 1; Material 3 > 9
>
> Material 1 > 2; Material 2> 2; Material 3 > 8
>
> Material 1 > 3; Material 2> 3; Material 3 > 7
>
> Material 1 > 4; Material 2> 4; Material 3 > 6
>
> Material 1 > 5; Material 2> 5; Material 3 > 5
>
> Material 1 > 6; Material 2> 6; Material 3 > 4

I think there should be a better way to do it.